# Place text inside of the svg polygon

Tags: css, svg

I have a polygon with a shape of a triangle. But the text inside of the polygon is not rendering. Any help is appreciated. This is what I tried so far, and I am not able to figure out why the text isn't rendering. Can I actually place a text inside of a polygon with points like this?

```
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
<polygon fill="#F3BC23" stroke="#F3BC23" stroke-width="1" points="30,4 4,60 60,60"/><polygon>
<text x="10" y="14" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="10"></text>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of problems with your SVG.

1. The `points` attribute in the `<polygon>` wasn't formatted properly.  It is missing commas.
2. You had a stray `<polygon>` tag at the end of that line.
3. You had no text in your `<text>` element.
4. The position of the text was not over the polygon. White text on a white background would be invisible.
5. I also increased the `font-size` so that the text was visible.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
  <polygon fill="#F3BC23" stroke="#F3BC23" stroke-width="1" points="30,4,4,60,60,60"/>
  <text x="32" y="50" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="30">X</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use the `<text>`

Here is Your Code

```
<svg>

<text x="10" y="10">text</text>

</svg>
```